# Are soundcloud streaming-urls constant

Tags: soundcloud

I have some soundcloud tracks I access via a website. 
The tracks are currently stored as 'nice' URLs e.g. `soundcloud.com/donjohnston/anagram`.
 
I then lookup the track/playlist via `api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?client_id={id}&url={url}`, and in the json-response find `stream_url`, which in this case would be: `api.soundcloud.com/tracks/27333421/stream`.

Is there anything to prevent that I store the `stream_url` instead - avoiding the extra lookup? I'm well aware that the numbers can be removed from the playlist or in general deleted from soundcloud, but otherwise the stream-url isn't changing, is it? (it's build around the track id..)

Or are there anything else I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

What you should basically store is the `tracks/{id}` parts – these are unique for every track / playlist (`playlist/{id}` respectively). With that you can construct the urls for track/playlist representation or the stream URL no problems.